# Can't Login To Two Asp.Net MVC 5 Application on the same browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership

I have Two Asp.net MVC 5 Applications running in the same server, when I login To the first one,I Automatically Logged Out From the second one ,And when I create user on both with the same username if login to one I login automatically in the other one ,I Don't Know what am doing wrong .
I user Microsoft visual studio 2013 default ASP.NET MVC 5 project Template.

Comment: are they at the same origin?

Comment: yes same no different configuration add

Comment: thats likely why - the cookie is getting overwritten

Comment: how can I prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if both apps are using the same application pool. Otherwise ensure they are not using the same back end data tables ie. the same Identity tables. If they overlap that could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by cookie name collision, if both applications are served from the same domain (`domain.com/app1` and `domain.com/app2`) or from subdomain of one of them (`domain.com` and `app.domain.com`) - your two applications may have a default authentication cookie name of `.ASPXAUTH`.

You can change the authentication cookie name in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".MYAPPASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Picking a unique name for each of your applications fixes the issue.